# ajax or post jquery method do refresh for page anyways

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have problem with snipped of jquery handler for email form submission:

Seems like submission 'hang on' when I use e.preventDefault otherwise it just load email.php page. So Any search, even add to html onSubmit="reutn false;" doesn't help. What's wrong?

if comment out preventDefault then everything works fine, but load email.php, if leave seems $ajax or $post dont do anything...

Search for prevent default, read documentation try to return false directly from script, I use jquery 3.4.1

```
 $(function() {
        var form = $('#email_form1');
        form.submit( function(e) {
            // problematic string
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    window.alert(data);
                    form[0].reset();
                    $('#mail_popup').magnificPopup('close');

                }
            });

        });
    });
```

I expect that ajax request will execute email.php in background but it loads this page...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in using jquery slim instead standard. it hangs on $ajax unknown method :( shame on me....